# Hibernate Many to Many relation not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I am in learning to use Spring & hibernate. Now I'm facing some issue with many to many relation in hibernate. My data is not saving in jon table. I dont know why. Please some one help me.
I have two domain classes call Projects & Technology.
this is my mappings in those two classes
Project class:-

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="project_technology",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="projectId")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="technologyId")})
public List<Technology> getTechnology() {
    return technology;
}
```

Technology class:-

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="project_technology",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="technologyId")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="projectId")})
public List<Projects> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}
```

in my DAo layer

```
getSession().beginTransaction();
getHibernateTemplate().save(projects);
getHibernateTemplate().clear()
```

Use for save data.It shows no error but data not saving in join table.

When I use

```
Session session = getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(projects);
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

to save, Data correctly save in join table.but after save Im gettin this error

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
```

My applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hibernateDataSourse" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>              
            <value>com.sla.tecprof.domain.Technology</value>            
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionProxy"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
    abstract="true" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="hibernateTransactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource" ref="transactionAttributeSource" />
    <property name="preInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="exceptionInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="TransactionPointCutAdvisor" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="postInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="hibernateInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a many-to-many issue. Check your service layer, is it annotated with Transactional, if not, then annotate it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment .Still same issue sir

Comment: Then your config is wrong, because this is not a mapping issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the @JoinColum Annotation on one side.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="project_technology",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="projectId")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="technologyId")})
public List<Technology> getTechnology() {
    return technology;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "technology")
public List<Projects> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}
```

Great resource for Hibernate annotations: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.This is what i did in my DAO leyer

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(projects);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
```